# setting div background with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know this is a completely basic question, but I cannot figure it out.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>omglol</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div2"> 
            <p> hello there you silly unicorn </p>
        </div>
        <script> 
            document.getElementById('div2').bgColor='blue'; 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So then by my reckoning, this should be changing the background of `div2` blue? This is not the case sadly. I am most distressed and considering listening to Justin Bieber.

Comment: A great page title and a very derogatory content. Well done for the proof-reading on that one!

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874560/how-to-use-javascript-to-change-div-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

`bgColor` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.bgColor) *(MDN)*.

---

## Solution

See [JavaScript DOM Element `style` property documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/API/element.style).

The proper way to change the **background color** of an element is to use the **style** object and to edit its `backgroundColor` property:

### JavaScript

```
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
div2.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

> *In JavaScript, backgroundColor corresponds to the CSS property background-color. JavaScript does not allow hyphens in names, so "camelCase" is used instead.* (*[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/JavaScript)*)

Comment: cheers for that. so um, whats the reason to declare it as a var first, and then change the property?

Comment: @SeraHolmes You don't necessarily need to declare a variable, but for the sake of a short example, this process clarifies the steps for anybody who might take a look at this page in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Do this...

```
document.getElementById('div2').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('div2').style.backgroundColor = "#00F"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pure JavaScript:-

```
document.getElementById('div2').style.backgroundColor = 'Color Code';
```

Using Jquery:-

```
$('#div2').css('background-color','color code');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here..

```
document.getElementById('div2').style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
document.getElementById('div2').style.background='blue';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider adding it to function `pageLoad()` like :

```
<script> 
    function pageLoad()
    {
        document.getElementById('div2').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
</script>
```