# change of background color of outer div on mouse hover (button) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed a pop up style window, which has a title bar & content section. Inside, the content section I have put a button too. I am trying to change the background color of title bar. I have made two classes (`title_bar` & `title_bar_hover`) which contain `background: linear-gradient();` property only. 
As per the solution given in this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305080/change-background-color-of-div) I have wrote the following jquery. I have added `jquery-ui` plugin as well.

```
$('#start').on('hover',function(){
    var target = $('.title_bar');
    target.addClass(".title_bar_hover");
},5);
```

But this code is unable to perform anything. However, here is the sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hitek_guy/8fPep/).
So please suggest some way(s) to achieve this functionality.
Thank you so much!

Comment: there no event called hover, you need to use hover method or mouseenter and mouseleave events

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9cLtX/1/

Comment: ohh.. sorry sorry..!

Thanks @ArunPJohny ..!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to:

1) Include jQuery in your `jsFiddle` demo

2) Use **[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** instead of `.on('hover',...`

3) Use **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** instead of `.addClass()`

4) Correct the class name as `title_bar_hover` in your CSS

```
$('#start').hover(function () {
    var target = $('.title_bar');
    target.toggleClass("title_bar_hover");
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fPep/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way:

```
$('#start').on('mouseover',function(){
        var target = $('.title_bar');
        target.toggleClass("title_bar_hover");
        });

$('#start').on('mouseout',function(){
        var target = $('.title_bar');
        target.toggleClass("title_bar_hover");
        });
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WZ7j/)

Comment: This can be simplified to:


`$('#start').hover(function() {`
    `$('.title_bar').toggleClass('title_bar_hover');`
`});`

Comment: Why should it be used?

Comment: in lastest jquery event are written using on so i prefer to use on

Answer (score 1):

With this you can toggle the class easily on hover.

```
$('.title_bar').hover(function(){
         $('.title_bar').toggleClass('title_bar_hover');
    }, function(){
         $('.title_bar').toggleClass('title_bar_hover');
    });
```

Hope its useful to you :)

[**JSBIN demo**](http://jsbin.com/mamew/2/edit)