# when click on button, background changes colour

Tags: javascript, colors

What i am trying to do, is when you click on a button, i want the background to change colour, from black to grey. But for some reason my code isn't working, i've tried multiply different ways but nothing seems to work, my code looks right but it fails to work. The html and the java has to be separate also. I would appreciate any help! thanks :)

here is my HTML

```
   <html>
    <body> <div id ="main"> <button type="Grey" id="Grey" onclick="colorControl(this)">
    Grey</button> </div> </body> </html>
```

and her is my JS

```
    var isGrey = true;
    function colorControl (el){ 
    if(isGrey){
    document.getElementById("main").style.color = ("#b8b8b8");
    isGrey= false;
    el.innerHTML = "Black";
    return;
    }
    document.getElementById("main").style.color = ("#b8b8b8");
    isGrey = true;

   el.innerHTML = "Grey";
   }
```

Comment: try get elementbytagname("body")[0].style.backround = whatever

Comment: Give this a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874560/how-to-use-javascript-to-change-div-backgroundcolor

Comment: Also, black = #000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style.color` changes the text color. You want to use `style.backgroundColor`