# How to change Style background Property using javascript, With onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change Style background Property using javascript, With onmouseover ?

When mouseover `not rate` Why `id="all_rating"` not change Style background Property ?

How can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/1x8rLLpt/

```
<div onmouseover="show_star('-12')">not rate</div>
<br>
<div class="all_rating" id="all_rating">
</div>


<script>
function show_star(bg_position) {    
    document.getElementById("all_rating").style.background = "transparent url(http://image.ohozaa.com/i/eb0/OZDobo.png) no-repeat 0px +bg_position+px;";    
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use javascript to change div backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874560/how-to-use-javascript-to-change-div-backgroundcolor)

Comment: May be its good time to start opening the console looking for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you need to close the quotes for string concatenation. JavaScript will not interpret variables in strings. You also don't need the semi-colon at the end of the string, it would invalidate the CSS property value.

```
document.getElementById("all_rating").style.background = "transparent url(http://image.ohozaa.com/i/eb0/OZDobo.png) no-repeat 0px " + bg_position + "px";
```

Also, I'd recommend only updating the `backgroundPosition` property, rather than the whole `background` property.

```
document.getElementById("all_rating").style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + bg_position + "px";
```