# How to change background color of div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this may seem very simple to many, but for me it isn't, so im here asking for your help.

I have a javascript function that returns some colors, and then a have a seperate div which should accept background color that comes from that function.

i get the result of function like this:

```
var _myColor = GenerateColor(value).color;
```

and the result of _myColor is: **#742322**

How would i force this color now inside div as my **background-color**

```
<div class="myColorClass" stlye="background-color:"></div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript to change div backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874560/how-to-use-javascript-to-change-div-backgroundcolor)

Comment: See [this](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery provides a method called `.css()`. If you pass one attribute (the css property like `background-color`) you get the value of this property.If you pass a second one, the second one will be the property's value.

```js
$("#mydiv").css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">This is my div.</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP says in the title `with javascript`

Comment: a very simple and clean solution. works perfect!. thank you!

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen He tagged it with jQuery, too. Nonetheless there are answers to this question already so instead of answering it, one should mark the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('myColorClass')[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution with  pure java script enjoy coding

```
  <div>
   <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="first input"></input>
      <input id="secondtext" type="text" placeholder="second text"></input>
   </form>
</div>
<div id="div1">
   hello
</div>
<button onclick="backcolor()">ClickToChangeColor</button>
function backcolor()
{
   document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```