# How to assign custom color to progress bar bootsrap 4

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Guys i have progressbar:

```
<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" style="width:{{a.49}}%">{{a.49}} %</div> </div>
```

How can i assign custom color to progress bar based on condititon in CSS ? :

```
if a.49 < 50 color red
if a.49 > 50 but less than 70 color orange
if a.49 > 70 color green
```

Would appreciate your help.

What i tried based on answers but cannot get the desured result  :

```
a=50

 <div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar" style="width:{{a}} %; background:{% if a < 50 %}red{% elif a > 70 %} green{% else %}orange{% endif %};">{{a}} % </div></div>
```

However though it colors inside bar in color based on value in this case orange, however the bar is filled by 10-20% whereas before it used to fill by 50% as the value of  `{{a}}`

like this :

```
<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" style="width:{{a}}% ;
       backkground:{% if a < 50 %} red {% elif a > 70 %} green {% else %} orange {% endif %}"> {{a}} %</div> </div>
```

is this method can be replicable to progress bar?

Comment: The easiest way is to apply style from your `JS` based on you desired conditions. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1874589/1958051) is the answer of how to apply color in `javascript`. Do you specifically need to do CSS side?

Comment: yes i would like to get css as i am not so familiar with js only ready codes. Would appreciate if you could share some code and seems to be complicated to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS variables and multiple background you can do it:

```css
.progress .progress-bar {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(green  0 0) 0/ calc(var(--w)*1% - 70%) 1px, 
    linear-gradient(orange 0 0) 0/ calc(var(--w)*1% - 50%) 1px, 
    red;
  width: calc(var(--w)*1%);
}

.progress .progress-bar::before {
  content: attr(style) "%";
  font-family:monospace;
  text-indent:-4ch;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

html {
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="--w:20"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="--w:80"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="--w:60"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: your porgress bar has 3 can you do 1 and apply three condition green orange red ? as i do not want to put 3 progress bars

Comment: @Chantel you don't need 3 progress bars. I used three to demonstrate that you only need to change the value of --w and the color will change automatically. Try yourself and see

Comment: hey i have the same type of question about css : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780581/how-to-assign-custom-color-in-google-column-chart-based-on-value-django  . Can i apply the code you shared to google column chart ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple JavaScript. Only warning is don't add any extra spaces on your "style" attribute or this won't work.

First, Change your progress bar code a little. You have to add new id="anyname".
I am going to use "progress" as my ID.

```
<div class="progress">
<div id="progress" class="progress-bar" style="width:{{a}}%">{{a}}%</div> 
</div>
```

Next, add the following javascript. It will get your percentage automatically and change color accordingly. I have a function that will do this.

Function:

```
    function formatbar(id) {
    div1 = document.getElementById(id);
    style = div1.getAttribute('style');
    percent = style.substring(6);
    a= percent.substring(0, percent.length - 1);

    if (a<50) {
    //color red
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if (a<70) {
    //color orange
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    } else if (a>70) {
    //color green
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    }
```

Now all we have to do, is call the function with the ID we provided.

```
formatbar(id);
```

Using this, you can make many progressbars like this. The only condition is each progress bar has to have it's own ID or this won't work.

```js
formatbar("progress")
formatbar("progress1")
formatbar("progress12")
function formatbar(id) {
div1 = document.getElementById(id);
style = div1.getAttribute('style');
percent = style.substring(6);
a= percent.substring(0, percent.length - 1);

if (a<50) {
//color red
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else if (a<70) {
//color orange
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "orange";
} else if (a>70) {
//color green
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
}
```

```html
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div  class="progress"><div id="progress" class="progress-bar" style="width:20%">20%</div> </div>
<div  class="progress"><div id="progress1" class="progress-bar" style="width:60%">60%</div> </div>
<div  class="progress"><div id="progress12" class="progress-bar" style="width:90%">90%</div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Django template language to do this without writing more CSS:

Template logic: 
`{% if a<50 %}red{% elif a<70 %}green{% else %}blue{% endif %}`

Plugged in:

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" style="width:{{a}}%; color:{% if a<50 %}red{% elif a<70 %}green{% else %}blue{% endif %};">
    {{a}} %
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: hey it does not work. Is that possible to create class "green" and assign color in css ?

Comment: @Chantel I'd recommend implementing the above, then inspecting element on a page to see that it's formatting correctly. "red" and "green" should be default css colors. I just edited my answer as I forgot to put a semicolon after width. Alternatively, if you want to define exact colors, you could do ```{% if a<50 %}#00FFFF{% elif a<70 %}``` using a hex code

Comment: hey your code just color number 50 but not the inside background color. So replaced color to background but the color is not filled 50 only 10-20. My code does fill automatically half blue 50 as value 50 if it is 100 it would be 100% filled by blue. Now i want to replace blue by custom color orange, green red

Comment: how to fix that issue?

Comment: @Chantel Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: the code you share just color number on the progress bar which is 50 in orange. I want to color progress whihc is by default blue color. So replaced color to background however when i did it it instead colors the progress-bar in orange however the color is filled only by 20% whereas it should be 50% as the value of a. Is that clear? Please have a look at my question i share there

Comment: @Chantel Look at my answer, I did using javascript