# Changing div background color on mouse-over with anonymous function calling from HTML code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have got this code from the below link and I am new to Javascript. I want to know how to call the JavaScript function from the html code.

Because they are anonymous functions I am unable to call them.
Could someone help me how to call those two function in the div?

Link : [How to use JavaScript to change div backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874560/how-to-use-javascript-to-change-div-backgroundcolor)

```
<div id="catestory">

  <div class="content">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>some content here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>some content here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>some content here</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
var div = document.getElementById('div_id');
div.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
  h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};
div.onmouseout = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
  h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
};
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `document.getElementById( 'div_id' );` to `document.getElementById( 'catestory' );`

Comment: 1 min will check

Comment: Top div or inside 3 div need to change the id

Comment: you only have 1 div with an ID, If you want it to run on the classes of the divs inside then look at the example I've provided

Answer (score 1):

Basicly all you have to change is `document.getElementById( 'div_id' );` to `document.getElementById( 'catestory' );`

but if you want all of them to have a seperated hover effect then try this:

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('#catestory .content');
for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
    h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
  div[i].onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
    h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  };
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('#catestory .content');
for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
    h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
  div[i].onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
    h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  };
}
```

```html
<div id="catestory">

  <div class="content">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>some content here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>some content here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>some content here</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Need to call that function inside html with onmouseove and onmouseout because it is not working for me, I copy the same code and check it is not working

Comment: @VyTcdc No problem happy to help

Answer (score 0):

The sample code works. Only change div_id with id of your div.

You can bind js events to html elements directly like:

```
<div onmouseover="myFunction()"></div>
```

For Example (the following code means inside the event quotes waits function names or can works javascript) :

```html
<button onmouseover="this.innerHTML = Date()" onmouseout="this.innerHTML = 'The time is?'">The time is?</button>
```

Or firstly find the html element with selectors and bind functions to related event like your sample.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('catestory');

div.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
  h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};

div.onmouseout = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  var h2s = this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
  h2s[0].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
};
```

```html
<div id="catestory">

  <div class="content">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>some content here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>some content here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>some content here</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: getting error like  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseover' of null

Comment: ok. be sure you add the id to your div. like: <div id="catestory">